# iOS - Searching Table View

Tags: ios, xcode, arrays, uitableview, search

This is my current search code.

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSString *)scope {
    [filteredList removeAllObjects];         
    for(Location *item in list)
    {
        NSRange result = [item.title rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
        if(result.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [filteredList addObject:item];
        }
    }
}
```

How would I change this to match any part of the title and not just the start.

Example:

At the moment if I search for 'Las', 'Las Vegas' will appear in the list, but when I search for 'Vegas' it does not.

I want the search term 'Vegas' to come back with 'Las Vegas'

Thanks,
Ashley

Comment: Just FYI, you might want to start using `NSPredicate`s with arrays via  `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`. It makes life a bit easier. Here's the Apple reference for predicate string syntax: [Predicate Format String Syntax](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [rangeOfString:options:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString%3aoptions%3a) instead of rangeOfString:options:range:. It is the `range` parameter that restricts the search to the beginning of the string.

Or if for some reason you want to use rangeOfString:options:range: then use this as range: `NSMakeRange(0, [item.title length])`

Comment: I can't believe that was all. Thanks